# my desktop menu is hidden even after reboot

Tags: xubuntu

my clock and applications and everything from the top is gone aswell as seeing which windows are open from the bottom of homescreen.  I know this will be simple but just cant do it.

Comment: Hit `Alt + F2` and try the following command `gconftool-2 --recursive-unset /apps/panel && killall gnome-panel`

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you're using gnome-classic(?)

Hit Alt-F2, type 'gnome-panel' (maybe you have to tick 'run in terminal', I don't know)

If the panel appears, click on it with Alt/right-click or Win/Alt/right-click and you can start adding indicators

Comment: Thanks for the response but no go i get an error saying no such file or directory.  I'm running xubuntu 10.04 and when i log in under admin both destop panel are there but there are not here on my account.  can still do everything i want its just annoying to not have the ease of using the panels.

Comment: Thanks for the response but no go i get an error saying no such file or directory. I'm running xubuntu 10.04 and when i log in under admin both destop panel are there but there are not here on my account. can still do everything i want its just annoying to not have the ease of using the panels.